# Error c2664 in VS 2013 C++

Tags: c++, oop, c2664

So, I have a class called "music" and when I try to compile the code, it gives me the following errors:

> Error 13  error C2664: 'music::music(const music &)' : cannot convert
>   argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'char'    c:\users\andrei
>   bordeianu\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\mediaplus\mediaplus\source.cpp  362 1   MediaPlus
>
> 14  IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "music::music" matches
>   the argument list
>               argument types are: (const char [5], const char [5], const char [4], const char [12], int, const char [8], const char [5],
>   int)  c:\Users\Andrei Bordeianu\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MediaPlus\MediaPlus\Source.cpp  361 11  MediaPlus

This is the class:

```
// Music class.
class music {
    char* song;
    properties musicProperties;

public:
    music() {
        cout << "Apel constructor default muzica." << endl;
        this->song = NULL;
    }

    music(char* songName, char name, char type, char path, float size, char artist, char title, int year) {
        cout << "Apel constructor cu parametri muzica." << endl;
        if (songName) {
            this->song = new char[strlen(songName) + 1];
            strcpy(this->song, songName);
            musicProperties.setDataMusic(name, type, path, size, artist, title, year);
        } else {
            songName = NULL;
        }
    }

    music operator=(const music &songName) {
        cout << "Supraincarcare operator = pentru muzica." << endl;
        this->song = new char[strlen(songName.song) + 1];
        strcpy(this->song, songName.song);
    }

    music(const music &songName) {
        cout << "Apel constructor de copiere muzica." << endl;
        if (songName.song) {
            this->song = new char[strlen(songName.song) + 1];
            strcpy(this->song, songName.song);
        } else {
            song = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~music() {
        cout << "Apel destructor muzica." << endl;
        if (this->song) {
            cout << "Apel destructor pentru: " << this->song << endl;
            delete[] song;
        }
    }

    friend char* getMusic(const music& m);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, music& m);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, music& m);
};
```

and this is the main:

```
void main() {
    music m1;
    music m2("ceva", "ceva", "mp3", "c:\data\music", 38, "Rihanna", "Stay", 2013);
    music m3 = m1;
}
```

---

Ok, tried your suggestions, and changed to string, and now my app looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Properties class.
class properties{
    string name;
    string type;
    string path;
    float size;

    // For images.
    int width;
    int height;

    // For music.
    string artist;
    string title;
    int year;

public:
    properties() {
        cout << "Apel constructor default proprietati." << endl;
        this->name = "";
        this->type = "";
        this->path = "";
        this->size = 0;
        this->width = 0;
        this->height = 0;
        this->artist = "";
        this->title = "";
        this->year = 0;
    }

    properties(string name, string type, string path, float size, int width, int height, string artist, string title, int year) {
        cout << "Apel constructor cu parametrii proprietati." << endl;
        this->name = name;
        this->type = type;
        this->path = path;
        this->size = size;
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
        this->artist = artist;
        this->title = title;
        this->year = year;
    }

    char getName() {
        return this->name;
    }

    char getType() {
        return this->type;
    }

    char getPath() {
        return this->path;
    }

    float getSize() {
        return this->size;
    }

    int getWidth() {
        return this->width;
    }

    int getHeight() {
        return this->height;
    }

    char getArtist() {
        return this->artist;
    }

    char getTitle() {
        return this->title;
    }

    int getYear() {
        return this->year;
    }

    void setName(string name){
        this->name = name;
    }

    void setPath(string path){
        this->path = path;
    }

    void setType(string type){
        this->type = type;
    }

    void setSize(float size){
        this->size = size;
    }

    void setWidth(int width){
        this->width = width;
    }

    void setHeight(int height){
        this->height = height;
    }

    void setArtist(string artist){
        this->artist = artist;
    }

    void setTitle(string title){
        this->title = title;
    }

    void setYear(int year){
        this->year = year;
    }

    void setDataGeneral(string name, string type, string path, float size){
        cout << "Apel setter general properties." << endl;
        setName(name);
        setType(type);
        setPath(path);
        setSize(size);
    }

    void setDataMusic(string name, string type, string path, float size, string artist, string title, int year){
        cout << "Apel setter music properties." << endl;
        setName(name);
        setType(type);
        setPath(path);
        setSize(size);
        setArtist(artist);
        setTitle(title);
        setYear(year);
    }

    void setDataImages(string name, string type, string path, float size, int width, int height){
        cout << "Apel setter image properties." << endl;
        setName(name);
        setType(type);
        setPath(path);
        setSize(size);
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
    }

    // Constructor de copiere.
    properties(const properties& p){
        cout << "Apel constructor copiere properties." << endl;
        this->name = p.name;
        this->type = p.type;
        this->path = p.path;
        this->size = p.size;
        this->width = p.width;
        this->height = p.height;
        this->artist = p.artist;
        this->title = p.title;
        this->year = p.year;
    }

    ~properties(){
        cout << "Apel destructor properties." << endl;
    };
};

// Music class.
class music {
    char* song;
    properties musicProperties;

public:
    music() {
        cout << "Apel constructor default muzica." << endl;
        this->song = NULL;
    }

    music(char* songName, string name, string type, string path, float size, string artist, string title, int year) {
        cout << "Apel constructor cu parametri muzica." << endl;
        if (songName) {
            this->song = new char[strlen(songName) + 1];
            strcpy(this->song, songName);
            musicProperties.setDataMusic(name, type, path, size, artist, title, year);
        } else {
            songName = NULL;
        }
    }

    music operator=(const music &songName) {
        cout << "Supraincarcare operator = pentru muzica." << endl;
        this->song = new char[strlen(songName.song) + 1];
        strcpy(this->song, songName.song);
    }

    music(const music &songName) {
        cout << "Apel constructor de copiere muzica." << endl;
        if (songName.song) {
            this->song = new char[strlen(songName.song) + 1];
            strcpy(this->song, songName.song);
        } else {
            song = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~music() {
        cout << "Apel destructor muzica." << endl;
        if (this->song) {
            cout << "Apel destructor pentru: " << this->song << endl;
            delete[] song;
        }
    }

    friend char* getMusic( music& m); //const
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, music& m);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, music& m);
};

// Movies class.
class movies {
    char* movie;
    properties moviesProperties;

public:
    movies() {
        cout << "Apel constructor default filme." << endl;
        movie = NULL;
    }

    movies(char* movieTitle, string name, string type, string path, float size) {
        cout << "Apel constructor cu parametri filme." << endl;
        if (movieTitle) {
            this->movie = new char[strlen(movieTitle) + 1];
            strcpy(this->movie, movieTitle);
            moviesProperties.setDataGeneral(name, type, path, size);
        } else {
            movie = NULL;
        }
    }

    movies operator=(const movies &movieTitle) {
        cout << "Supraincarcare operator = pentru filme." << endl;
        this->movie = new char[strlen(movieTitle.movie) + 1];
        strcpy(this->movie, movieTitle.movie);
    }

    movies(const movies &movieTitle) {
        cout << "Apel constructor de copiere filme." << endl;
        if (movieTitle.movie) {
            this->movie = new char[strlen(movieTitle.movie) + 1];
            strcpy(this->movie, movieTitle.movie);
        } else {
            movie = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~movies() {
        cout << "Apel destructor filme." << endl;
        if (this->movie) {
            cout << "Apel destructor pentru: " << this->movie << endl;
            delete[] movie;
        }
    }

    friend char* getMovies(const movies& m);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, movies& m);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, movies& m);
};

// Images class.
class images {
    char* image;
    properties imagesProperties;

public:
    images() {
        cout << "Apel constructor default imagini." << endl;
        image = NULL;
    }

    images(char* imageName, string name, string type, string path, float size, int width, int height) {
        cout << "Apel constructor cu parametri imagini." << endl;
        if (imageName) {
            this->image = new char[strlen(imageName) + 1];
            strcpy(this->image, imageName);
            imagesProperties.setDataImages(name, type, path, size, width, height);
        } else {
            image = NULL;
        }
    }

    images operator=(const images &imageName) {
        cout << "Supraincarcare operator = pentru imagini." << endl;
        this->image = new char[strlen(imageName.image) + 1];
        strcpy(this->image, imageName.image);
    }

    images(const images &imageName) {
        cout << "Apel constructor de copiere muzica." << endl;
        if (imageName.image) {
            this->image = new char[strlen(imageName.image) + 1];
            strcpy(this->image, imageName.image);
        }
        else {
            image = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~images() {
        cout << "Apel destructor muzica." << endl;
        if (this->image) {
            cout << "Apel destructor pentru: " << this->image << endl;
            delete[] image;
        }
    }

    friend char* getImages(const images& i);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, images& i);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, images& i);
};

char* getMovies(const movies& m) {
    if (m.movie)
        return m.movie;
    else
        return NULL;
}

char* getImages(const images& i) {
    if (i.image)
        return i.image;
    else
        return NULL;
}

char* getMusic(music& songName) { //const
    if (songName.song)
        return songName.song;
    else
        return NULL;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, music& s) {
    out << "Melodia este: " << s.song << endl;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, music& s) {
    char buffer[20];
    cout << "Melodia: "; 
    in >> buffer;
    s.song = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
    strcpy(s.song, buffer);
    return in;
}

void main() {
    music m1;
    music m2("ceva", "ceva", "mp3", "c:\data\music", 38, "Rihanna", "Stay", 2013);
    music m3 = m1;
    //cout << getMusic(m2) << endl;
    //cout << m2;
    //cin >> m2;
    //cout << m2;
}
```

and it gives me the following error(s):

> Error 1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to
>   'char'    c:\users\andrei bordeianu\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\mediaplus\mediaplus\source.cpp  50  1   MediaPlus

etc...

What can I to to resolve this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: Did you **actually read** your error message before you slapped it onto a question? The error tells you *exactly* what's wrong.

Comment: I'm a newbie in OOP CPP

Comment: And? The error message isn't going to bite. **Read it** and try to interpret what it says. If you never read error messages, you'll *never* be a good programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
music(char* songName, char* name, char* type, char* path, float size, char* artist, char* title, int year);
```

since char is a single character not pointer to a C string. Even better you should use a modern string class instead of old pointer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass string types ("ceva", "mp3", etc) into char parameters. To solve this, change your constructor parameters from `char` to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

In the signature, the function accpects a char for name, but you send a char*.
`music(char* songName, char name, char type, char path, float size, char artist, char title, int year)`

I think it should be:
`music(char* songName, char* name, char* type, char* path, float size, char* artist, char* title, int year)`

Answer (score 0):

You got your anwser, use string types or pointers.

As to why this is happening: You are passing characters as values, which mean they get their own new char array instance, this is clashing with the const instance of the argument. This is why the first argument (which was an explicit pointer) didn't cause an error.